# can anyone explain how getchar is being used here to take input of sequence of number?

Tags: c, io, getchar

can anyone explain how getchar is being used here to take input of a sequence of numbers?

```
main()
{
  int digit;
  int number;

  digit = (int) getchar() - 48;
  number = 0;

  for (; (digit >= 0) && (digit <= 9); ) 
  {
    number = number * 10 + digit;
    digit = (int) getchar() - 48;
  }

  printf("%d\n", number);
}
```

Comment: A quick review of the [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) should make clear what is going on. Though using `- '0'` is much more readable than `- 48` (lesson -- always use the *character-literal* instead of its ASCII value). There is no need to cast `(int)getchar()` -- the return type for `getchar()` is already `int`.

Comment: You really should indent your codde.

Comment: The ironic part is underneath all that awkwardness, the basic logic isn't bad (it actually covers EOF and non-digit entry). However the good parts of the code are almost unrecognizable due to the awkward way it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking user input in C or when reading from a text file, all input is character input -- even if those characters read are `"123"` (which would the the ASCII characters `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'`) If you look at the [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) you will see characters that are digits have the ASCII values (shown in Decimal, Octal and Hexadecimal):

```
     Char  Dec  Oct  Hex
    ---------------------
     0      48 0060 0x30
     1      49 0061 0x31
     2      50 0062 0x32
     3      51 0063 0x33
     4      52 0064 0x34
     5      53 0065 0x35
     6      54 0066 0x36
     7      55 0067 0x37
     8      56 0070 0x38
     9      57 0071 0x39
```

Those are simply the ASCII codes for each of the characters `'0' - '9'` shown above

So you read an ASCII character, one of the digits with `getchar()`, then how do you get the integer value for that digit? Meaning how do you turn the character `'1` int the integer `1`? Since the ASCII character for `'0'` has the ASCII decimal value of `48`, if you wanted to obtain the integer `0` from the ASCII digit `'0'`, you simply subtract the ASCII character value for `'0'` from it. (which makes since when you thin about getting the integer `0` from character `'0'`, you simply subtract it from itself leaving zero.

For the other ASCII digits `'1' - '9'`, notice how they are ordered in sequence after `'0'` in the character set. So if ASCII `'1'` has the decimal value `49` and you want to get the integer value `1` from it, what number do you have to subtract from `49` to end up with `1`? (hint: `48` or the readable `'0'`). So all subtracting the ASCII value for `0` from your ASCII digit does is result in a conversion of that ASCII digit to its integer value.

The logic of your code isn't bad, but it is written very awkwardly. Whenever you have a question on how a C function works, read the man-page for that function, e.g. [man 3 fgetc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html). There you will see the return type for `getchar()` is already `int` so there is no need to cast the return of `getchar()` to `(int)`, it is superfluous.

Your loop simply multiplies the current `number` by `10` and then adds the new integer to that number so you are building a final integer value out of each of the ASCII digits you read from input. Instead of the manual comparisons `(0 <= digit && digit <= 9)`, the `<ctype.h>` header provides the `isdigit()` macro that provides that test in a standard way. Also, as noted in the comments, don't do `- 48` instead make what you are doing readable by using the *character-literal*, e.g. `digit - '0'` which is easily recognized as a conversion of an ASCII digit to its integer value.

Putting all those pieces together, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

    int digit = getchar(),                  /* read 1st character from stdin */
        number = 0;                         /* initialize number zero */

    if (digit == EOF || !isdigit(digit)) {  /* validate not EOF and digit */
        fputs ("error: manual EOF or non-digit input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    digit -= '0';   /* subtract ASCII val for '0' from digit to obtain integer value */

    while (1) {                             /* loop continually reading digits */
        number = number * 10 + digit;       /* add current digit to number */
        if (!isdigit(digit = getchar()))    /* read next digit, validate digit */
            break;                          /* on non-digit; break loop */
        digit -= '0';                       /* subtract '0' for integer value */
    }

    printf("%d\n", number);     /* output integer that results from digit conversion */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With some example numbers and letters, you can see how the function was intended to work:

```
$ echo "135" | ./bin/atoimin
135

$ echo "23a" | ./bin/atoimin
23
```

(**note:** how character extraction stops when a non-digit is found after a digit has already been processed.)

But see what happens when the non-digit is the first character read:

```
$ echo "a23" | ./bin/atoimin
error: manual EOF or non-digit input.
```

Look over the code and the logic and let m know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

See the sample code below

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n=0;
    char ch=getchar();
    n=(ch-'0');
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Note:Your input must be 1 digit and range 0-9 only.

Let as assume you give input 5 and the [Ascii](http://asciitable.com) value of `'5'` is 53  and ascii value of `'0'`  is 48

so

```
    53-48=5
```

so the value of n is 5.